# Webpage not available after converting Query String paramter in sub-domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have converted URL query to sub-domain, but web-page returns `webpage not available`.

This is my code in `.htaccess`, Do i have to do any more settings in `apache configuration` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ http://%1.example.com/$1? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Kindly Help.
Thanks

Comment: Can you ping this subdomain ?

Comment: It say host not found!

Comment: @JohnCargo That's your problem right there. If the host can't be found, then your browser is just telling you that it can't find it. Is there a DNS record for the subdomain in question?

Comment: @EdCottrell , do i need to specify DNS record for each sub-domain, that cannot be done manually, As user will keep registering and it will keep taking them to their sub-domain, and for each sub-domain, it says host not found. 
I am not sure, how these guys are doing it : http://www.litmos.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work. Your big problem isn't your `.htaccess` file, but your lack of DNS records for your subdomains. You need to specify a [**wildcard**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) at the DNS level. You also need to [**setup Apache virtual hosts using a wildcard**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html).

As for your `.htaccess` file, note that it will only match if `index.php` is present in the URL. To match all requests, like `http://example.com/?user=foo`, `http://example.com/bar.php?user=foo`, or `http://example.com/baz/bar.php?user=foo`, use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.example.com/$1? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly, what i am looking for, can you please elaborate more with 1 example for setting up `wildcard DNS` and `setting up Apache Virtual host using a wildcard`.

Comment: That's fairly broad, but it boils down to this: In your `httpd.conf` (or, if you use an include file for the VirtualHost section for your web server config, in that include file) add a line like this, if it is not already present: `ServerAlias *.example.com`. You also need to set up an `A` DNS record for `*.example.com` and point it at your server. You can read more about this at, for example, [the Wordpress page on wildcard subdomains](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains) or [the Apache HTTPD docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html).

Comment: Just waiting for my `A` record `DNS` to work. It's not yet working. But i think , that's my host issue. Let me get it confirmed, and will award the `bounty` once confirmed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help! It can take a little while for the DNS to propagate, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: Yes, but usually it takes 5 min-2 hour. Finger-Crossed. Let's see. Thanks

Comment: Any luck? Any chance you can share your real domain name so we can check the DNS?